# Is there any way to make phone call from my app with using my custom activity?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Is there a way to make a phone call from my application, so that I can use my own design/theme, record the received voice, clean the transmitted voice, etc.?

Comment: Please try google search first and come up with a specific problem because you can find tons of resources regarding this somewhere.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/telecom/selfManaged